# react-native custom fonts error unrecognized font-family

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fonts, custom-font

I need to use custom fonts in react-native- in iOS it is working Fien. but on iOS it giving error. unrecognized font-family. I have follow many tutorials but none is working in my case.
Here are some links that I have followed.

[link 1](https://medium.com/@alcides.bsilvaneto/installing-custom-fonts-ttf-or-otf-on-react-native-0-60-projects-e8dafbc0dff3)

[link 2](https://dev.to/aneeqakhan/add-custom-fonts-in-react-native-0-63-for-ios-and-android-3a9e)

[link 3](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1074)

Here are two issue. if the fonts are added in `copy bundle resources` then it produce `multiple command error` and if I remove these from this then the project build but it give error `unrecognized font family`
I have added then in `react-native-config.js` font files are visible in resources file and also in the info.plist file. but there are n0t working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: have you solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create File "react-native.config.js" not "react-native-config.js"

After add the font try react-native link otherwise manually add fonts in Resources in xcode project.

Try this medium link https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4

Comment: yes, the name of the font should be as per the xcode wants